# install pip on windows 10 with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, pyopenssl

I am new to python and i need to install virtualenv.
I need to use python 2.7 on windows.

First I tried installing pip by downloading get-pip.py and running below command

```
python get-pip.py
```

then I got below errors

> https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
> pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
> c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmp6zqwwn\pip.zip\pip_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:387:
> SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Server
> Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform.
> This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate,
> which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer
> version of Python to solve this. For more information, see
> https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
> c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\tmp6zqwwn\pip.zip\pip_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:142:
> InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available.
> This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause
> certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of
> Python to solve this. For more information, see
> https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
> WAR

I tried searching solutions of above errors

Found solutions saying to install pyopenssl with below command
which itself requires pip

```
pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
```

So its kind of loop i get into.

found below command as well

```
python -m ensurepip
o/p --> No module named ensurepip
python -m pip install urllib3[secure]
o/p --> No module named pip
```

Tried searching to install **pyopenssl** without pip but couldn't find any working solution.

Can anyone suggest me how can i install pip on windows 10 with python 2.7 ?

Please suggest !

**Note:- can't upgrade to latest python version**

**Thanks in Advance !**

Comment: I recommend not installing it on windows at all. If you don't need GUIs, use [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). Search for Ubuntu 18.04 on the Microsoft Store, install it, and launch it. Then just type `sudo apt install python2.7 python2.7-pip`, and the rest gets taken care of. The windows terminal is a pain to use compared to Ubuntus.

Comment: "The windows terminal is a pain to use compared to Ubuntus", i agree to this, but i have to use windows only. Any solution that will work on windows in the case mentioned ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can check a checkbox when installing python2.7 graphically to install pip along with it. [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) seems to suggest that you're using an old python2.7 version, as pip should already be installed. Try creating a venv, or reinstall python. Just to make sure though: You're aware that WSL runs on windows and links into the windows filesystem, right?

Comment: Thanks Nearoo for you response. I have checked the link you posted it says
"pip is already installed if you are using Python 2 >=2.7.9"

i am using python 2.7.0. I am not aware of WSL as of now, but as i am using my company laptop so i wont't be able to install WSL on it.Also not sure if i can install python 2.7.9